# Plot multiple lines in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, line

I try to plot lines in a loop,but its connecting it,i tried many variants,but cand understand and find the answer,maybe the dataframe
im a newbie in Matplotlib
the code of method:
self.testnewnewventnest[Debit] - is a nested dict with the data i need for plotting

```
        def showmainplot(self):
    for Debit in self.Debitlist:
        self.Presinit = self.VentTable.loc[Debit]
        self.Tinit= float(self.Tinit)
        self.Presinit=int(float(self.Presinit))
        self.Powinit = float(self.Powinit)
        x = symbols("x")
        for Turatie in self.Tfin:
            eqPres = (Turatie/self.Tinit)*(Turatie/self.Tinit)*self.Presinit-x
            PresFin = solve(eqPres)
            eqDebit = (Turatie/self.Tinit)*int(Debit)
            DebitFin = solve(eqDebit)
            eqPow = (Turatie/self.Tinit)*(Turatie/self.Tinit)*(Turatie/self.Tinit)*float(self.Powinit)
            self.TestnewVentnest['KW'] = float(eqPow)
            self.TestnewVentnest['Turatie'] = Turatie
            self.TestnewVentnest['Presiune'] = float(PresFin[0])
            self.TestnewVent[float(eqDebit)] = dict(self.TestnewVentnest)
            self.testnewnewventnest[Debit] = dict(self.TestnewVent)
    print(self.testnewnewventnest)
    axeslist = []
    n=0
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
    ax1 = ax.twinx()
    ax1.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.06))
    ax.set_xlabel("Debit")
    for dicts in self.testnewnewventnest:
        Ventdataframe = pd.DataFrame(self.testnewnewventnest[dicts])
        print(Ventdataframe)
        ax2 = plt.subplot()
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
        ax1 = ax.twinx()
        ax1.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.06))
        ax.set_xlabel("Debit")
        axeslist.append(plt.subplot())
        # print(df.iloc[0])
        # ax1.set_ylabel("Turatie")
        # ax.set_ylabel("Presiune")
        # Ventdataframe.plot(Ventdataframe.loc["Presiune"], color="b",label="Presiune"+str(n),marker = 'o')
        Ventdataframe.loc["Presiune"].plot(color="b",label="Presiune"+str(n),marker = 'o')
        n+=1
        # ax2 = ax.twinx()
        # ax2.set_ylabel('KW')
        # ax1.plot(Ventdataframe.loc["Turatie"],color='#000000',label="Turatie",marker = 'o')
        # ax2.plot(Ventdataframe.loc["KW"], color='r',label="KW",marker = 'o')
        # ax1.grid()
        # ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(Ventdataframe.loc["KW"]))
        # ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(Ventdataframe.loc["Presiune"]))
        # ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(self.Tfin))
        # ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(Ventdataframe.columns))
        # lc = matpl.ticker.NullLocator()
        # ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(lc)
    plt.show()
```

and the self.testnewnewventnest look like:

[image]

[image: plot]

[image: A part of Dataframe Ventdataframe exported and converted to .csv]

Yes,the problem was in the loop,and in the dictionaries,in every iteration he added all previous dictionaries from iterations

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you want no connection between data points at all or only some connected and others not?

Comment: i want that in every new iteration,to draw a new line,but he connect the new iteration to past

Comment: Something looks strange: In ```for dicts in self.testnewnewventnest:
        Ventdataframe = pd.DataFrame(self.testnewnewventnest[dicts])``` you are looping over the elements of self.testnewnewventnest and then you use them to access self.testnewnewventnest' elements again.... How does self.testnewnewventnest look like?

Comment: hey,i posted more code,i have the elements x-that is a index of dict,i create a dataframe from dict[x]

Comment: Concerning readability: You are looping over keys of the dictionary self.testnewnewventnest, so would suggest to rename ```dicts``` to ```key``` or something meaningful. However, since you anyway just need the values of this dictionary, you can also loop over these directly: ```for sub_dict in self.testnewnewventnest.values(): Ventdataframe = pd.DataFrame(sub_dict)```

Comment: In general it looks to me that the dictionaries you are passing to pd.DataFrame contain in each loop the data of the previous dataset. Therefore all data points are connected. You need to make sure that each dataset only contains the datapoints which should be connected.

Answer (score 0):

I would put that in a dataframe and do it like this.

```
uniques = df['ID'].unique()

for i in uniques:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.set_size_inches(4,3)
    df_single = df[df['ID']==i]
    sns.lineplot(data=df_single, x='Month', y='Expense')
    ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Total Expense')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.show()
```

[image]